# Cómo pasar primera letra de un párrafo a mayuscula? Programa powershell

Tags: powershell

Tengo una problema con las teclas shift de mi teclado y siempre las uso para sacar mayúsculas rápido.
Veo como solución que se salga automáticamente al iniciar el párrafo un texto.

solamente he encontrado esto.

```
$palabra="palabra"
$palabra.substring(0,1).toupper()+$palabra.substring(1).tolower()
```

la idea es un programa en segundo plano que reconozca el teclado.

Answer (score 0):

Ya hay una metodo especifico que hace lo que pides, este se llama: `ToTitleCase`

Puedes hacer una funcion como esta

```
function to_upper($tu_input){

    $info = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
    $mayus = $info.ToTitleCase($tu_input)

    return $mayus

    }
```

de forma que cada vez que se dé la condicion que quieras:

```
to_upper -tu_input $palabra_guardada
```